# Duplicate check for comma separated array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, duplicates, logic

I am trying to check duplicate in the following array, just i am want to return true or false if duplicate exists.

```
var array = ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Saturday" ];

for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

for (var j = i+1; j< array.length; j++){

if (array [i] === array [j]){

console.log(array[i]);
}
}

}
```

I tried the above , it giving result only for one item in an array not for comma separated. How i can write a duplicate check function in best way for comma separated array?

```
Array(10)
 0: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"1: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"2: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"3: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"4: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"5: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"6: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"7: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"8: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"9: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: oh, so your real array has string values that have commas in them, they're just strings, the commas mean nothing special - so what do you want to test exactly? the code will check and output the duplicates (i.e. all 10 are the same)

Comment: i just want to return true if not duplicates and false for duplicate exists

Comment: so, return true where you `console.log` ... return false outside of the loops

Comment: `new Set(array).size === array.length` is true if all array items are unique

Comment: `a.map(item=> item
.split(',').map(child => child)).map(item => new Set(item).size === item.length)` try by doing this may be this solves your problem

Comment: i need to check only first item in the array for duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in a `Set` will always be **unique**, as it only keeps one copy of each value you put in. Here's a function that uses this property:

```js
function hasDuplicates(iterable) {
  return  new Set(iterable).size !== iterable.length;
}

// Demo
var array = ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Saturday" ];
console.log(hasDuplicates(array))

// Returns True if there is duplicates
// Otherwise return false
```

`Set(iterable).size` will return the count of unique elements in that set, while `iterable.length` is the counts of all elements in the original array.

**Edit #1**

To check ONLY the first item for duplicates you can use something like this

```js
var array = ["Saturday",  "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday" ];


console.log(array.indexOf(array[0] , 1) === -1 ? "No duplicates" : "Has duplicate" );
```

Comment: i need to check only first value of comma separated values for each item in the array for duplicates

Comment: please consider the second array in the question

Comment: Which second array? there is only one in your question!

Comment: Array(10)
 0: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"1: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"2: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"3: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"4: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"5: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"6: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"7: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"8: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"9: "test3,tier 1,test,test2
"length: 10

Comment: Thanks for helping, i made the final solution here as another answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check duplicates in upload data excel

    checkDuplicates(arr) {

        if (arr.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

                    if (arr[i].split(',')[0] === arr[j].split(',')[0]) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```